# How to add tab to UITabBar controller ? iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I use storyboard and I have a uitabbarcontroller with some connected view controllers. How to add new tab to tabbarcontroller without `"relationship segue"` and connected ViewController. I want to change behaviour of this tab and add custom handler(make this tab like a button), but i can't add tab without connected view controller.

In my situation, click on "Downloads" tab should perform Push segue to 'test' navigation controller and pass some data to it. How to implement it in a right way?

I overrided method:

```
class BarController:  UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate  {

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    switch viewControllers?.index(of: viewController) {
    case 0?:
        return true;
    case 1?:

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TestSegue", sender: nil);

        return false;
    default:
        return true;

    }      
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to connect your last VC with no segue and pass data.am I right...

Comment: I want to add tab and set custom behaviour on it(it should not be connected with any controllers). I want to implement same logic like in Instagram app. When you touch tab with camera icon, it behaves like a button and creates new VC where you can select photos.

Comment: You could use UIToolBar instead of tabBarController.In toolBar you can easily setup a tabBar icon and connect your VC from it.If you want to connect your VC without a segue you need instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method.Let me know what you thing...

Comment: Thanks, i have several tabs with connected VCs, but i want only one tab with other behaviour. UITabBar should be displayed permanently, but not in VC which is called by my custom tab.

Comment: So you want to connect that Specific Vc .But,you don,t want any view transition is that right....